# Can Apache DirectoryScanner handle paths with parent directory references?

Tags: apache, ant

everyone,

I'm using Apache's DirectoryScanner like this:

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"/home/John/../Alex/file"});
scanner.scan();
String[] filePaths = scanner.getIncludedFiles();
```

The problem is DirectoryScanner does not find the target file when there is parent directory reference in the path (John/../Alex).

If the path is "/home/Alex/file" it works as expected.

Is there a way Apache's DirectoryScanner to handle this kind of paths, or the scanner just does not support them?

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've found a work-around. It seems DirectoryScanner expects canonical paths. The above code works with the following change:  

`String canonicalPath = new File(path)).getCanonicalPath("/home/John/../Alex/file");
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{canonicalPath});`

It's not required the target file to exists for the above conversion.